# Data does not get updated on the table view from one view to the next

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

What I am trying to do is moving from one table view controller to another. I am sending some data and the data is passed but id does not get updated in the table view. That is, when i click on one of the options in the table view, it shows the same screen again. Here is the code snippet I am using to push the table view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    devicedetailTableViewController *detailViewController = [[devicedetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

// NSLog(@"%@",detailViewController.details);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    detailViewController.details = self.data[indexPath.row];

}
```

Please help! Please note: I am not using storyboard here because the previous screen is a login screen ad segues are causing a problem for me there. So I decided to switch to code only. So, I cannot use storyboard.

PS: I know that the data is getting passed because i can see it in my log.
This is how I am loading data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibname"
                                                bundle:nil]
                            forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [self devices];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Name";
            break;
        case 1: {
            NSString *battlife = [details objectForKey:@"battlife"];

            cell.textLabel.text = battlife;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Battery Life";
            break;
            }
        case 2:{
            cell.textLabel.text = [details objectForKey:@"location"];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Location";
            break;}

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are pushing the view before setting the data,

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
detailViewController.details = self.data[indexPath.row];
```

do first the data set then push

```
detailViewController.details = self.data[indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

also you might need to do [table reloadData] depending on how u load the data on the second VC

Comment: I know this might be a very stupid question but I am newbie at IOS , where exactly do i do reload data? And i tried the other way you mentioned as well, but i did not work!

Comment: Right now I am doing reload data in View:DidLoad of the devicedetailTableViewController. Is it the right place to do it?

Comment: do the reload on viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear

Comment: on viewDidAppear, do log of your self.data

Comment: Logged it, and the data comes just fine in the log.

Comment: if it comes on log, reloadData should work, do you have the table datasource and delegate hooked up?

Comment: Yes I do have the datasource and delegate hooked up!